# Why does the email verification does not have the link working

Tags: laravel, email, verify

So, the verification is partly working. It sends an email but it does not have a working link to verify.

here is an example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS0cP.png)

Here is my code from the controller:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'token' => str_random(40)
    ]);

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

    return $user;
}
public function verifyUser($token)
{
    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::where('token', $token)->first();
    if(isset($verifyUser) ){
        $user = $verifyUser->user;
        if(!$user->verified) {
            $verifyUser->user->verified = 1;
            $verifyUser->user->save();
            $status = "Your e-mail is verified. You can now login.";
        }else{
            $status = "Your e-mail is already verified. You can now login.";
        }
    }else{
        return redirect('/login')->with('warning', "Sorry your email cannot be identified.");
    }

    return redirect('/login')->with('status', $status);
}
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'We sent you an activation code. Check your email and click on the link to verify.');
}
```

This is from the view:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome Email</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Welcome to the site {{$user['name']}}</h2>
<br/>
Your registered email-id is {{$user['email']}} , Please click on the below link to verify your email account
<br/>
<a href="{{route('verify.user', $user->verifyUser->token)}}">Verify Email</a>
</body>

</html>
```

User class:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'name';
    }
    public function verifyUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\VerifyUser');
    }
}
```

To me everything seems fine. It does not show any exceptions but it still does not work. I got an email but  I can not verify.

Comment: Can you show us the `User` class as well?

Comment: From what I can see so far, you are generating the verification mail from `$user` variable, which, as far as I can see, does not hold the `->verifyUser` property at the time. Also, you are accessing the `email` value as an array, but in the controller, you access the `email` as a class property: `Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));`. Showing the `User` class will definitely show what is going on.

Comment: User class uploaded.

Comment: is your view a `.blade.php` file?

Comment: In the template, you are missing brackets when calling method verifyUser. It should be `$user->verifyUser()->token`. Without brackets it should raise a notice `Undefined property: User::$verifyUser`. I suggest enabling [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in devepment mode, so you can see all the levels of errors.

Comment: Can you also provide the static method `User::create`, so we can figure out the problem with email?

Comment: Now, the link is visible but leads to a empty page and it does not verify anything

Comment: Here is a link:
https://www.google.com/url?q=http://localhost:8000/user/verify/S2E5mg0H56AOpksFduUFDagdpmMCMLyqdnMB7ACv&source=gmail&ust=1544798724252000&usg=AFQjCNFyQya-exS3eHyHAWwPZ1oIoYWN6g

Comment: @Dejv What do you mean by User::create, it is already there

Comment: On 4th line of the Controller code you have provided, you are calling `public static method create(` of class `User`. I need to see the body of that method. It is not in the scope of what you've provided.

Comment: Well, everything you see is what I have. Nothing more. @Dejv